# How do you make a List with two sections where you can move items between both sections, even when one section is empty?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a List that has two sections. And I want to be able to drag items between both sections. Is that possible with List?

```
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Section 0")) {
                
                ForEach(section0) { item in
                    Text(item.title!)
                }
                .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                    
                })
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title!)
                }
                .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                    
                })
            }
        }
```

The problem I facing is that if a section has no items, then the section header is right on top of the next and there is no place to let it drop. I cannot make a placeholder, because that still makes it not a valid target.

I fear that the only way this can be achieved is by creating the list as a collection view with drag/drop. If I were doing that, how would that work?

Comment: Moving rows between two ForEach containers is not supported now in SwiftUI.

Comment: Could this possibly be achieved with having a drop target that is basically invisible that also has the .onMove?